# subclassing method showing error in the site-package in virtual environment

Tags: python, django

the **init**.py file shows error while running the file in importing subclassing method

```
(env) devbase@bounce:~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djorm_pgtrgm$ python __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import Field, subclassing
ImportError: cannot import name subclassing
```

i am new to python so it would be helpful if someone can tell me about the error
.............Thanks!!!

```
from django.db import backends
from django.db import connection
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import Field, subclassing
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
try:
    # Django 1.7 API for custom lookups
    from django.db.models import Lookup
except NameError:
    from django.db.models.sql.constants import QUERY_TERMS
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.sql.query import ALL_TERMS


db_backends_allowed = ('postgresql', 'postgis')
```

This is small part of code where i am importing the subclassing

Comment: Why are you running a `__init__.py` file inside an installed package as a script?

Comment: ... what do you expect to happen when running an `__init__.py` file? They are not meant to be run...

Comment: I am trying to solve the issue which comes while running the manage.py file while running the server with the same error.and I am trying to run the older project with same configuration in my local machine.

Comment: @RiyaGupta: your Django version is way too new for that code. Downgrade to Django 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

The project you are using is trying to import a module that only exists in Django versions up to 1.9. You can't use that code with Django 1.10 and newer. The 0.3 version of the released package only works with Django 1.7 or older due to other changes in the 1.8 and 1.9 Django releases.

Development of the [specific project you are using](https://github.com/jleivaizq/djorm-ext-pgtrgm) has stalled a long time ago. The [last release of the project on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/djorm-ext-pgtrgm/#files) was 4 years ago, and [that release was already out of date in March 2016](https://github.com/jleivaizq/djorm-ext-pgtrgm/issues/21). The source code [was last updated to follow Django changes for version 1.9](https://github.com/jleivaizq/djorm-ext-pgtrgm/pull/19) in 2015, and since then only two minor pull requests have been merged, both in 2016.

Unless you know how to how Django internals and how that project was using them in detail and so can update the project yourself, I'd consider the project entirely dead. Move on, and forget about this codebase.

If you are trying to bring to life a legacy Django project, then make sure you are using Django 1.7 or older. The 0.3 version of the project that you have installed can't work with anything newer than that.